# how to use filename-regex option in int-ftp:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

I defined ftp outbound adapter with `ls` command and recursive mode in my spring integration project. I want to filter and get files in specified `sub-directories`. The directory structure on the server is:

```
root  
----------a\  
---------------in\  
---------------------a.op   
----------b\   
---------------in\  
---------------------b.op
```

I want to get the `a.op` and `b.op` files. I set the `filename-regex` option to `([a-z]|in|.*\.op)` but it did not work correctly and only the first level directory is filtered. My adapter code is:

```
 <int:inbound-channel-adapter expression="'/'" channel="inbound">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="20000"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>
 <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                              session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound"
                              command="ls"
                              filename-regex="([a-z]|in|.*\.op)"
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload"
                              reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try using `\b([a-z]\\in\\.*?\.op)\b` regex.

Comment: thanks for reply @stribizhev but not worked correctly :(

Comment: How about this `(in|.*.op)` ?

Comment: thanks for reply @ArtemBilan, not worked the  `in` directory in second directory level in my ftp server

Comment: What does it return by using `(.*\.op|^[^\.]+$)` as the pattern?

Comment: thanks for reply @revo, not worked correctly

Comment: Would you show me the output?

Comment: expected result: `a.op` ,  `b.op`

Comment: I don't mean expected result. I mean the output you get from `(.*\.op|^[^\.]+$)`

Comment: oh sorry , output with `(.*\.op|^[^\.]+$)` is all files that have `.op` extension.

Comment: Okay @alireza, now tell me about `([ab]\.op|^[^\.]+$)`

Comment: thanks but not worked  :( return empty result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77389/discussion-between-revo-and-alireza-alallah).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`filename-regex="([a-z]|in|.*\.op)"`

The regex is applied during the recursion.

Given your tree structure:

The first `ls`, returns [a, b].

These are passed by the first optional regex element [a-z].

The second and fourth `ls` returns `in`, passed by the second part.

The third `ls` returns `a.op`, passed by the last part.

The fifth `ls` returns `b.op`, passed by the last part.

Comment: thanks for reply @Gary Russell, only first level worked , if file exists in directory `a` and have extension `.op` return in result.

Comment: The regex is applied on each recursion so it should work; I suggest you use a debugger.

Comment: i use `ls` command , filename-regex option supported in command?

Comment: the file with `.in` in each directory contain in result,i want to files with `.in` extension only in `in` directory contain in result.

Comment: that's right @Gary,but when file exists in `a` directory , for example: `a/test.op` contain in the result for me.

Comment: In that case (not wanting to obtain `.op` in the intermediate directory) then you are out of luck. You might be able to achieve your wishes with a custom `FileListFilter`.